# Filter an array of objects based on multiple conditions in typeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, kendo-grid

Hi team I have an array of objects like

```
data = [
  { name: "Pork", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" },
  { name: "Pepper", category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" },
  { name: "Beef", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" },
  { name: "banana", category: "Food", subcategory: "Fruit" }
];
```

Here i need to filter the `data` array based on the filter condition

```
{
   "filters":[
      {
         "filters":[
            {
               "field":"subcategory",
               "operator":"eq",
               "value":"Vegetables"
            }
         ],
         "logic":"or"
      },
      {
         "filters":[
            {
               "field":"name",
               "operator":"eq",
               "value":"Pepper"
            },
            {
               "field":"name",
               "operator":"eq",
               "value":"banana"
            }
         ],
         "logic":"or"
      }
   ],"logic":"and"
}
```

I can do this simply using `process()` in `Kendo` like

```
kendo.data.Query.process(data, {
  filter: {
    logic: "and",
    filters: [{
      field: "subcategory",
      value: "Meat",
      operator: "eq"
    }],logic:"or"
  }
});
```

So is there any other way to filter like this without using `process()` ?

Comment: What is the difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes ?

Comment: Difference is here i have an array of filters. means the conditions can be like [{
price <= 1000,
    sqft >= 500, 
    num_of_beds >=2, 
    num_of_baths >= 2},{
price <= 500,
    sqft >= 500, 
    num_of_beds >=2, 
    num_of_baths >= 2}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach takes a `filters` object which contains an array and a logic part as quantifier for the conditions.

The array can contain other objects with `filters` quantifier as `logic` or an object with the constraints for a single property which have to match an item of the given data array.

Actually only one operator is implemented.

```js
const
    operators = { eq: (a, b) => a === b },
    quantifiers = { and: 'every', or: 'some' },
    filter = ({ filters, logic }) => item => filters[quantifiers[logic]](f => 'filters' in f
        ? filter(f)(item)
        : operators[f.operator](item[f.field], f.value)
    ),
    filters = { filters: [{ filters: [{ field: "subcategory", operator: "eq", value: "Vegetables" }], logic: "or" }, { filters: [{ field: "name", operator: "eq", value: "Pepper" }, { field: "name", operator: "eq", value: "banana" }], logic: "or" }], logic: "and" },
    data = [{ name: "Pork", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" }, { name: "Pepper", category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" }, { name: "Beef", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" }, { name: "banana", category: "Food", subcategory: "Fruit" }],
    result = data.filter(filter(filters));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: Hi Nina, this will return empty array for the condition     filters = [{ field: "subcategory", value: "Meat", operator: "eq" },{ field: "name", value: "Pepper", operator: "eq" }],

Comment: `every` works as logical AND amd it looks like you need `some`, which works as logical OR.

Comment: Nina, there was a mistake in structure of filter condition. I have updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Please have a look.

Comment: How to handle if the logic is 'AND' for the outer filter?

Comment: By default for the outer logic the value is "AND".  So i changed "filters.some()" to "filter.every()"

Comment: it would be easier if you add some more data, a nested filters array and the wanted result of it.

Comment: I cant reveal the actual array and filters, its very confidential. Thats why I created this dummy example. Anyway I will try to create a more example

Comment: Could you help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657673/iterate-json-and-display-item-based-on-a-dynamic-array-of-objects